# Odd error when trying to run Tux in Sinatra (error: undefined method `needs_migration?')

Tags: activerecord, sinatra

I'm trying to run Tux in a Sinatra app, but I keep getting this error:

undefined method `needs_migration?' for ActiveRecord::Migrator:Class

I've tried running bundle update and a lot of other fixes, but nothing is working. Does anyone know what this error means and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had some left over code in `config.ru` that I had to remove:

`` if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?
  raise 'Migrations are pending. Run `rake db:migrate` to resolve the issue.'
end ``

Check your project for the this if you're using ActiveRecord > 5.0